# Change Default Location for All User Home Directories in Mac OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, mac

How can I change the default location for all user home directories in Mac OS X 10.10.5?

I have found plenty of articles about moving a single folder at a time, but no instructions on how to change the default on all new users that are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the existing user folder to a new location

```
ditto /Users /newpath
```

Setup a symlink to redirect to the new path

```
ln -s /newpath /Users
```

Or you can do it all in one line

```
ln -s -F /newpath /Users
```

Comment: I will mark this as an answer because for most cases it will suffice for most people. However, it does not truly change the default, and the main drawback is that some applications (such as Dropbox or Google Drive) do not work well with symlinks.